# Fuse errors when installing packages in Debian 8

Tags: debian, apt

I'm getting fuse errors when trying to install packages with apt-get.
I've tried reinstalling it but it didn't help.

This is output when I try to install something:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up fuse (2.9.3-15+deb8u2) ...
Creating fuse device...
/run/udev or .udevdb or .udev presence implies active udev.  Aborting MAKEDEV invocation.
chmod: cannot access '/dev/fuse': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 6):

Hey its very simple to fix:

```
mkdir /dev/fuse
chmod 777 /dev/fuse

apt-get install fuse
```

Comment: This solution worked surprisingly well. I don't see why it was downvoted. I had the same problem, and simply by creating the dir with those perms, the fuse install problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

This is potentically a duplicate of ["E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" when I try and install OpenVPN. What is this?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-when-i-try-and-install): a package tried to install `fuse` (probably as a dependency), however the configuration of the package failed since `udev` did not create `/dev/fuse`.

You might check the output of `$ service udev status` to see whether the service is running and `$ modinfo fuse` to verify that the kernel module exists.

If you are running inside a VM that shares a kernel with the host, chances are your VM is not allowed to use FUSE.

To get rid of the error, `apt-get remove fuse`.

Hth,
dtk

Answer (score 0):

This worked very well for my Pi Model B+ V1.2 running Raspbian GNU/Linux VERSION=8 (jessie).

- I only had to do:

  ```
  mkdir /dev/fuse
  chmod 777 /dev/fuse
  ```

  since my system already had `fuse` in it's latest version

Comment: In my case must remove this file, then run `apt install --reinstall ntfs-3g`